# RESTful API call in SSIS package

Tags: vb.net, ssis

As part of a SSIS (2005) package I am calling a RESTful API through a script component (VB.NET).  I am getting the records back OK.  The problem I have though is processing the format it comes back in so I can output it (split into the separate output columns) within the data flow and write into a SQL table.  Don't know where to start - anyone got any ideas?  I have no control over the API so am stuck with this format.

Here is the schema as per the API documentation:

```
{StatusMessage : <string>, Unit : <string> [ { VehicleID : <int>, RegistrationNumber : <string>, DistanceTravelled : <double>} ] }
```

And here is a sample of the data returned (it comes back as a single line of text):

```
{"VehicleDistance":
   [
    {
       "VehicleId":508767,
       "RegistrationNumber":"BJ63 NYO",
       "DistanceTravelled":0.09322560578584671
    },
    {
       "VehicleId":508788,
       "RegistrationNumber":"BJ63 NYL",
       "DistanceTravelled":6.1591048240661621
    },
    {
      "VehicleId":508977,
      "RegistrationNumber":"PE12 LLC",
      "DistanceTravelled":60.975761413574219
    },
    {
      "VehicleId":510092,
      "RegistrationNumber":"BJ64 FCY",
      "DistanceTravelled":14.369173049926758
    },
    {
      "VehicleId":510456,
      "RegistrationNumber":"BJ63 NYY",
      "DistanceTravelled":4.04599142074585
    },
    {
      "VehicleId":513574,
      "RegistrationNumber":"BL64 AEM",
      "DistanceTravelled":302.150390625
    }
  ],
  "StatusMessage":null,
  "Unit":"imperial",
  "HttpStatus":200
  }
```

Comment: Have a read of this, try the sample then ask any specific questions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136060.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks for this.  I am fine to work out the script component side of things.  The issue is more dealing with the strange format of the data as it comes back.  If it was XML that would make it easier.  Need to iterate through record by record and split the data into the fields.  I suspect this will be purely VB.NET code rather than anything directly related to SSIS.

Comment: So you can handle the script source component, you just can't come up with an algorithm to shred the JSON that you are being sent?

Comment: Yep, that's it.  Didn't recognise the format of the output and poor documentation - I'll do some reading on JSON now I have a name for it! But any guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: http://dennysjymbo.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/using-json-feed-as-data-source-in-ssis.html looks relevant - now I know I'm dealing with JSON.  Thanks for your help Nick.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of of formatting the JSON. Hopefully you can see that you can use simple string functions to turn this into columns and rows? In this case the 'data' is between the square brackets and each 'row' is between each curly brace. JSON allows  complex unbalanced nested data but in your case (and many other cases) it's just a table represented in a serialised format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Javscript Object Notation AKA JSON and you need to deserialise it. The problem is that using SSIS is tricky with third party tools that are popular (and fast) but VB.Net actually has a built in class to serialise and deserialise JSON called JavaScriptSerializer

First add a Reference to your project called System.Web.Extensions and then you can use the JavaScriptSerializer to deserialise your JSON.

I've put your JSON in a file for easier handling so first I have to...

```
Dim sJSON As String = ""

Using swReadFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("E:\JSON.txt")
    sJSON = swReadFile.ReadToEnd()
End Using
```

The rest is the pertinent bit, so first add 2 Imports...

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
```

Then for example we can...

```
Dim lvSerializer As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()

lvSerializer.MaxJsonLength = 2147483644

Dim dictParsedJSONPairs As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = lvSerializer.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(sJSON)

If dictParsedJSONPairs.ContainsKey("VehicleDistance") AndAlso _
   TypeOf dictParsedJSONPairs("VehicleDistance") Is ArrayList Then

    Dim ArrayEntries As ArrayList = DirectCast(dictParsedJSONPairs("VehicleDistance"), ArrayList)

    For Each ArrayEntry As Object In ArrayEntries

        Dim DictEntry As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = DirectCast(ArrayEntry, Dictionary(Of String, Object))

        If DictEntry.ContainsKey("VehicleId") Then Console.WriteLine("VehichleId:" & DictEntry("VehicleId"))

    Next

End If

If dictParsedJSONPairs.ContainsKey("Unit") Then
    Console.WriteLine("Unit is " & dictParsedJSONPairs.Item("Unit"))
End If
```

Clearly you should research JSON before launching into serious use. The object can be nested JSON (i.e. Dictionary(Of String, Object)), a number of some sort, a string or an ArrayList

Comment: Thanks for that.  Unfortunately as I am running SQL Sever 2005, with .NET 2, System.Web.Extensions is not available :( (introduced in .NET 3.5).

Comment: Yes, that's true. I didn't check before I started on this though and I've just knocked this code up in VS2005. It worked but I also have all sorts of other things installed so it's probably something else that allows it. Ah well, perhaps it will help someone else at some point.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Marked it as an answer as in most cases this will do the job as you say.  I have seen a TSQL solution which will parse JSON - slightly messy and probably not comparative in performance, but not dealing with that much data so might be an option for me to explore.  Unfortunately upgrading SQL is not in this year's budget.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bit late but you may want to have a look at json.net from Newtonsoft ([website](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)). The component provided contains .Net 2.0 version.

Using it in a SSIS script task is quite simple. I did it in SSIS2008 based on .Net 3.5 to parse JSON string like below. And according to the document, it should work for .Net 2.0 version as well.

```
//I assume you had obtained JSON in string format
string JasonBuffer;

//define Json object
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(JasonBuffer);

//In my example the Json object starts with result  
JArray Results = (JArray)jObject["result"]; 

//loop the result
foreach (JObject Result in Results)  
{  
   //for simple object
   JObject joCustomer = (JObject)Result["Customer"];
   //do something...

   //for complex object continue drill down 
   foreach (JObject joSection in Result["Sections"])       
   {
       foreach (JObject joDepartment in joSection["Departments"])  
       {  

         foreach (JObject joItem in joDepartment["Items"])  
         {  

         }
```

You can find some actual code here: [link](http://sqlcodespace.blogspot.com.au/2015/01/simpro-ssis-part-3-loop-entity.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did come across json.net in my googling and was considering using it, but instead I went for a TSQL function - https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/.  Whilst I am aware TSQL is not the best way of doing this for performance, the dataset is only around 30 records at a time so not much of a concern.  And as I am familiar with TSQL I was able to get this up and running in an hour or so.  It's working well now.